# How to do inversion on int

Tags: java

for example I have such number `4302033`, it is in binary system `10000011010010011010001`, and I need to make inversion, but when I do inversion, it turns out so `11111111101111100101101100101110`, and how to take away these units in the beginning

Comment: what you call inverse of a number? bitwise inverse, additive inverse, multiplicative inverse (probably not), ...?

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong!

The binary representation of 4302033 is not 10000011010010011010001!

In fact it is 000000000010000011010010011010001.

In Java, an `int` has 32 bits (check `Integer.SIZE`), always, no matter how large the number is that you store within that `int` field. Even for zero, it has those 32 bit (Ok, the first (most left) bit is not really used for the value, but for the sign).

This means that when you invert an `int`, you invert all these 32 bits, even including those left from the first 1 (those you referred to as "these units at the beginning").

If this is unwanted, you have to take precautions against that:

```
var value = 4302033;
var leadingZeros = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros( value );
var inverted = value ^ 0xFFFFFFFF << leadingZeros >>> leadingZeros;
System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString( value );
System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString( inverted );
```